# Excel: count items from A and sum up value from B if identical

Tags: excel

I want to do something very similar to what's been asked and answered here, although I don't want to have duplicates: [Find count of items in column and add the values from another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324308/find-count-of-items-in-column-and-add-the-values-from-another-column)

Basically, I have a `column A` with duplicated names, and different values associated in `column B`. In `column C` I want the name and in `column D` the summed up value. The problem with `SUMIF` is that it will show me several time the name and the summed up values, while I want to see it only once.

To make it more clear, here's the result I'm looking for:

```
     A        |    B     |    C      |    D
  ------------+----------+-----------+---------
    Name      |  Value   |   Name    |   Sum
  ------------+----------+-----------+---------
  Potatoes    |    9     |  Potatoes |    13
  Tomatoes    |    4     |  Tomatoes |    11
  Carrots     |    1     |  Carrots  |    16
  Potatoes    |    4     |  Eggs     |    5
  Eggs        |    5     |           |    
  Tomatoes    |    7     |           |
```

Comment: I've seen references to it when searching Stack Overflow, but I don't know anything about it or how to use it. I'm checking some tutorial now (https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/pivottbls/create.php)

Comment: Well, I just did the table and it's exactly what I wanted. Thank you :) Is there a way to then filter to get the values in a decreasing order, or do I need to copy the values in another column and then order this new column?

Comment: Ok, I thought maybe you had the answer, I'll try that :) Thanks!